# return value from inner class

Tags: android, json, inner-classes

i want to get my array in method `getDataJSON()` from inner class
this is a part from my code 
the function `getdatajson` will fill the arraylist with the returned array `dataJSONarray` from 
the inner class `getJsonFromServer`

how can i do it?

```
public ArrayList<note> getdatajson() {
    ArrayList<note> list = new ArrayList<note>();//to verify

    new getJsonFromServer().execute();

    return list;
}

private class getJsonFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            //make connexion with web server
            URL url= new URL("http://192.168.1.18/pfe/");
            URLConnection urlConnection= url.openConnection();

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader= new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String ligne;
            while ((ligne = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                jsonArray= new JSONArray(ligne);
            }

            //convert data from json array to java object
            Gson gson= new Gson();
            dataJSONarray= gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), dataJSON[].class);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can return dataJSONarray from doInBackground to onPostexecute and from that you can use it.

Comment: how can i get the return of onPostexecute into my method getdatajson() ?

Comment: If you have created the async class inside the activity then you can call any method you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a separate class like this. You can use `AsyncTask` in your existing class. The job of `AsyncTask` is to perform asynchronous operations. The framework provides you a method called `onPostExecute`. You can use it to do any operations that you want.

Please see the example below.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}
```

This sample code is taken from [Android Developer Website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).